# postgresql count rows with special columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, counting

my table looks like this:

table1:

| ident | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 |  | 4 |  |  |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |  | 3 |
| 6 |  | 3 | 2 |  |
| 7 |  |  | 3 |  |
| 8 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 9 | 1 |  |  |  |

Now i need something like a analysis from that table.
It should look like:

table2:

| name | just_name |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 0 |

the column just_name count the columns from table1 where there are no other entry in the other columns exept the ident column.
in the real table there are more than 4 columns so i better not work with a where for every other column. :)

thx

Comment: I think output for `A` might be 3 as I can see from then input table.

Comment: you are right. i corrected it.

Comment: Number of column is not fixed but is number of row fixed? Is it always 9?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as columns:

```
select count(*) filter (where A is not null and B is null and C is null and d is null),
       count(*) filter (where A is null and B is not null and C is null and d is null),
       count(*) filter (where A is null and B is null and C is not null and d is null),
       count(*) filter (where A is null and B is null and C is null and d is not null)       
from t;
```

You could also express this as:

```
select c.colname, count(*) filter (where c.num_vals = 1)
from t cross join lateral
     (select colname, count(colval) over () as num_vals
      from (values ('a', t.a), ('b', t.b), ('c', t.c), ('d', t.d)) v(colname, colval)
      group by colname
     ) c
group by c.colname;
```

This returns the values in separate rows.  And it is a bit easier to generalize.

Comment: but if i have all from A to Z it would not work like this.

Comment: @hahakomisch . . . And you would have a different question.  This answers the question that was asked here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with just putting the column names in column list then below query can get you your desired result. Though it's possible to make those part dynamic but if you know your column names and it's not changing dynamically this will be better approach. Please let me know if you wanna have hat part dynamic olso.

**Schema:**

> ```
> create table mytable1(ident int, A int, B int, C int, D int);
> insert into mytable1 values(1,null,2,1,null);
> insert into mytable1 values(2,3,null,null,null);
> insert into mytable1 values(3,1,2,1,5);
> insert into mytable1 values(4,null,4,null,null);
> insert into mytable1 values(5,4,1,null,3);
> insert into mytable1 values(6,null,3,2,null);
> insert into mytable1 values(7,null,null,3,null);
> insert into mytable1 values(8,1,null,null,null);
> insert into mytable1 values(9,1,null,null,null);
> ```

> 

**Query:**

> ```
> with cte as (SELECT
>    unnest(array['A', 'B', 'C','D']) AS Columns,
>    unnest(array[A, B, C,D]) AS Values,
>    row_number()over(order by 1)rn
> FROM mytable1),
> cte2 as (
> select rn,max(cte.columns)col,count(*) from cte   
>  where values is not null
> group by rn
> having count(*)=1)
> select distinct columns as name,coalesce(just_name,0)  from  cte left join (select col,count(rn) just_name from cte2
> group by col)t on cte.columns=t.col
> ```

**Output:**

> | name | coalesce |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 3 |
> | C | 1 |
> | D | 0 |
> | B | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0981ef3d4f218478462d70fb2e8d6a63)*